# If column 4 is a match, sed replace column 9; else replace column 9 with something else

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

When reading in a very large tab-delimited file that looks like:

```
.   .   .   A   .   .   .   .   3:.:.:20
.   .   .   B   .   .   .   .   4:.:30
.   .   .   C   .   .   .   .   5:.:.:40:.
.   .   .   D   .   .   .   .   .:.:.:.
.   .   .   A   .   .   .   .   7:.:.:21
.   .   .   B   .   .   .   .   .:.:.:.
.   .   .   D   .   .   .   .   .:.:.:.
.   .   .   C   .   .   .   .   .:.:.
```

I would like to keep column 9 as .:.:.:. only if column 4 = D. For all other column 4 values, I have a separate sed replacement query. The desired output will look like:

```
.   .   .   A   .   .   .   .   1:.:.:80
.   .   .   B   .   .   .   .   1:.:80
.   .   .   C   .   .   .   .   1:.:.:80:.
.   .   .   D   .   .   .   .   .:.:.:.
.   .   .   A   .   .   .   .   1:.:.:80
.   .   .   B   .   .   .   .   1:.:.:80
.   .   .   D   .   .   .   .   .:.:.:.
.   .   .   C   .   .   .   .   1:.:80
```

My current pseudocode is something like:

```
if [column 4 = D]
    then
        # either replace or just keep original entry
        sed '/some replacement query/g' {file}
    else
        sed '/some other replacement query/g' {file}
fi
```

I was thinking if I could read in the file row by row, maybe I could employ this method? But then I'm constantly writing to update a new file.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this time efficiently while staying in the shell environment. Since the end goal is to create one large end file, my current route creates two distinct versions that are incorrect. Maybe there's a way to do what I want within a single sed query? But that's beyond my expertise.

Edit: The sed replacement query currently looks at column 9 and determines the number of field separators (":") and replaces it with a respective value, i.e. `3:.:.:20` becomes `1:.:.:80` , `4:.:30` becomes `1:.:80` , and `5:.:.:40:.` becomes `1:.:.:80:.` The values between the field separators can be either digits 0-99 or a "." value. If, however, column 4 = N, column 9 has to turn into (or in this example, remain the same) `.:.:.:.` My current replacement query turns `.:.:.:.` into `1:.:.:80` which I don't want.

```
sed 's/\t\(\.\|[0-9]\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\)$/\t1:\.:\.:80/g; 
s/\t\(\.\|[0-9]\):\([0-9],[0-9]\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\)$/\t1:\.:\.:80:\./g; 
s/\t\(\.\|[0-9]\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\)$/\t1:\.:80/g'
```

Comment: Are the `.` representing tabs?  especially in the last field?  or those are just some arbitrary value?

Comment: The `.` are all placeholders for other column values, except for the last field, that's generally what the column looks like, so `./././.` is a single column string

Comment: Can you use `awk` or are you restricted to `sed`?

Comment: I can use awk as long as I can still use my very specific sed queries for the replacements... (let me know if that doesn't make sense)

Comment: @anita `awk` doesn't understand `sed` queries specifically; it has its own language for editing strings. (`sed`, on the other hand, doesn't understand columns.) What is the actual change you want to make? It might be expressible in `awk`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I understand. My sed command a very specific query, that's why I didn't include it... `sed 's/\t\(\.\|[0-9]\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\)$/\t1:\.:\.:80/g; s/\t\(\.\|[0-9]\):\([0-9],[0-9]\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\)$/\t1:\.:\.:80:\./g; s/\t\(\.\|[0-9]\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\):\(\.\|\([0-9]\+\)\)$/\t1:\.:80/g'` Basically all it's doing is identify the string length of column 9, and replace it with the respective length replacement. In this query, column 9 actually looks like 3:.:.:20 (different from my q. example)

Comment: Doing this with sed makes no sense at all. A single call to awk is the right approach. So if you really are constrained to "use my very specific sed queries for the replacements" as you stated in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796355/if-column-4-is-a-match-sed-replace-column-9-else-replace-column-9-with-somethi#comment121582830_68796355) then it's hard to be motivated to help you do that. Whatever that sed command in your other comment does I'm sure can be implement far more concisely in awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Okay, it's fixed now. I didn't switch it yesterday because I was already getting answers and didn't feel like the field separators were an important detail, but for clarity, now everything should match in my comments and the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you **really** need to hard-code these mappings but there's no other explanation in your question for how to come up with them so, assuming you do, then this will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"

    str2str[".:.:."]      = "1:.:80"
    str2str[".:.:.:."]    = "1:.:.:80"
    str2str[".:.:.:.:."]  = "1:.:.:80:."

    for (str in str2str) {
        re = str
        gsub(/\./,"(.|[0-9]+)",re)
        re2str["^("re")$"] = str2str[str]
    }
}
$4 != "D" {
    for (re in re2str) {
        if ($9 ~ re) {
            $9 = re2str[re]
        }
    }
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
.       .       .       A       .       .       .       .       1:.:.:80
.       .       .       B       .       .       .       .       1:.:80
.       .       .       C       .       .       .       .       1:.:.:80:.
.       .       .       D       .       .       .       .       .:.:.:.
.       .       .       A       .       .       .       .       1:.:.:80
.       .       .       B       .       .       .       .       1:.:.:80
.       .       .       D       .       .       .       .       .:.:.:.
.       .       .       C       .       .       .       .       1:.:80
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is usually better at the field-oriented stuff but it can be
done with `sed`: unless column 4 is `D` extract column 9, edit and
append as column 10, and finally delete column 9.

**EDIT**: updated to use `:` as subfield separator (was `/`).
**EDIT2**: clarified that `\t` isn't POSIX or for macos.

```shell
sed -E -e '
/^([^\t]*\t){3}D\t/b            # special case: dont edit if D in column 4
h                               # copy line to hold space
s/^([^\t]*\t){8}([^\t]*).*/\2/  # set pattern space = column 9
s/^[^:]+/1/                     # set first subfield = 1
/([0-9]+){2}|[^:]+$/ s//80/     # set 2nd digit group or last subfield = 80
x                               # exchange pattern and hold spaces
G                               # append \n+hold space to pattern space
s/\n/\t/                        # replace \n with field separator
s/[^\t]*\t//9                   # delete (old) column 9
' -- file
```

Additional comments:

- tab is field separator; if your `sed` doesn't understand `\t`
  (GNU `sed` does, but perhaps not on macos) - or to make the script POSIXly correct - replace `\t` with a literal tab character
- the empty regex in `s//80/` reapplies the last one used (in `/…/`)
- uses `-E` option for
  [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)
  extended regular expressions

Comment: When I try this, there are still 10 columns, except where column 4 = D. Thank you for all the explanations though

Comment: @anita: with GNU sed 4.7 my script produces exactly the desired output. Which `sed` are you using? (`sed --version`)

Comment: @anita: What's the output if you run the script and pipe it into ` | sed -n l | head -n 1` ? At my end I see `.\t.\t.\tA\t.\t.\t.\t.\t1:.:.:80$`.

Comment: I'm on mac, so there's no version listed (even in the binary) so that could be why. Let me try on my linux machine real quick instead

Comment: This answer worked on linux (sed v. 4.2.2), but not on mac

Comment: @anita: It's a POSIX thing: replace `\t` with a literal tab character (all of them), then it should work on macos, too. (Tested with `sed --posix -E -e ...`)

Comment: That didn't fix it unfortunately. There also isn't a "--posix" option for sed on mac.

Comment: @anita: Replacing `\t` with literal tab makes the script POSIXly correct, to the best of my knowledge, thus making it max. portable. I have one suggestion left: try `-r` option instead of `-E`. As I cannot test using sed on mac I'm not going to take this further.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I did try it with the literal tab character as well. It gives `unbalanced brackets ([])` error. The `-r`option replacement didn't work either (with `\t` or literal tab characters). This solution worked for me on linux, but just for record keeping, this method doesn't work on mac. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '$4!="D"{sub(/^[0-9]+|^\./,"1",$9);sub(/[0-9]+$|\.$/,"80",$9)} 1' Input_file
```

***OR*** In case you have TAB separated values in Input_file then add `BEGIN` section to above program as follows:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
$4!="D"{
  sub(/^[0-9]+|^\./,"1",$9)
  sub(/[0-9]+$|\.$/,"80",$9)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using `awk`.

```
cat file | awk '{if ($4 != "D") { sub($9, "Replaced the ninth field" ); print } else { print }}''
```

This will substitute the 9th field (`$9`) with the string if the 4th field ($4) is not a `D`.

You could also replace `$9` with a regex if you know the shape of the last field well enough, like `/\d\/\.\/\d$` or something.  Not sure if you also need back reference replacement in there.

But this might be a start.

```
cat out.tsv | awk '{if ($4 != "D") { sub($9, "Replaced the ninth field" ); print } else { print }}'
. . . A . . . . Replaced the ninth field
.   .   .   B   .   .   .   .   Replaced the ninth field
.   .   .   C   .   .   .   .   Replaced the ninth field
.   .   .   D   .   .   .   .   ./././.
.   .   .   A   .   .   .   .   Replaced the ninth field
.   .   .   B   .   .   .   .   Replaced the ninth field
.   .   .   D   .   .   .   .   ./././.
.   .   .   C   .   .   .   .   Replaced the ninth field
```

Comment: Whoops.  I realized my if/else is wrong.  you want replacement if it's column 4 is *not* a D.  I'll submit an update.

Comment: Do not use cat to get data inn to program that can read itself.  `awk 'code' out.csv`
 http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: That would convert all chains of tabs and blanks in the input to single blank chars.

Comment: `if (x) { foo; print } else { print }` = `if (x) { foo } print`. Whenever you find yourself writing duplicate code (e.g. `print`) take a second to think if you really need to do that or if there's a better way to structure your code to avoid it.